# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Tags: php

Мне нужно было вставить таблицу в скрипт, сделал вот так:

```
<table align=\"center\" valign=\"top\" width=\"60%\" bgcolor=\"#60B88D\" class=\"border-table-content\">
<tr style=\"margin: 20px; display: block;\">
<td>
<b class=\"NewsName\"><i>echo $name;</i></b><br />
<u class=\"NewsDate\">echo $putdate;</u><br /><br />
<strong>echo $body;</strong>
<hr width=\"98%\"></hr>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Выдает ошибку

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/u841538557/public_html/news.php on line 182 (182 строка самая первая в таблице)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените Ваш код на следующий:

```
?>
<table align="center" valign="top" width="60%" bgcolor="#60B88D" class="border-table-content">
<tr style="margin: 20px; display: block;">
<td>
<b class="NewsName"><i><?php echo $name; ?></i></b><br />
<u class="NewsDate"><?php echo $putdate; ?></u><br /><br />
<strong><?php echo $body; ?></strong>
<hr width="98%"></hr>
</td>
<?php
</tr>
</table>
<?php
```

Comment: `
<?php
</tr>
</table>
`

**<?php** надо здесь убрать.

А мне надо именно, чтоб таблица была записана в php.

Comment: Я решил проблему сам, спасибо за то что хотя бы попытались мне помочь)

Answer (score 0):

Вообще да, в php можно помещять различные теги html вне кода php. Приведу пример с оператором if:

```
<?php

$a=4;

if ($a<5) {    ?>

<p>Переменная "а" равна <?=$a?></p>

<?php  }  ?>
```

в данном случае строка `<?=$a?>` то же самое что `<?php echo $a; ?>`

Comment: Это к чему вообще?